# Sorting table with jQuery in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-plugins, tablesorter

I want to sort the table using jQuery instead of fetching data again and again from database. Here is my razor view of users, I don't want any paging or else I just want to sort the table in current view using jQuery. I have also attached the jQuery required libraries in my app that are

```
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>


<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.UserName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LName)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Password)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Role)
        </th>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UserName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LName)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Password)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Role)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("", "", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "DetailsUser", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID })
            </td>
        </tr>
}
</table>
```

I added the script and changed the id of table but it's not working. I also tried the solution [here](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html), I want the same.

```
<table id="keywords">

   <script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('#keywords').tablesorter(); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: what plugin you are using?

Comment: i am using this jquery.tablesorter

Comment: Check your browser console and see if you are getting any errors?

Comment: there are no errors but the <th> tags are not clickable

Comment: Did you include necessary plugin? Can you post a screenshot of what you have now?

Comment: @GuruprasadRao i am new in asp.net with jqery if u have any steps to add the functionality in asp.net mvc application then guide me please and sorry i dnt have enough badges to post and image

Comment: Move `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>` line above `<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Add the `debug` option then look in the console to see if there are any issues: `$('#keywords').tablesorter({  debug: true });`

Comment: Sorry guys none of them are working

Comment: Please share the rendered HTML... I think you're missing a `<thead>` and `<tbody>`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You all but i found the solution in WebGrid, it have the property of ascending and descending sorting of columns

```
var grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, rowsPerPage: 20);//add this in viewbag brackets at the top of page/razor View

    @using (@Html.BeginForm("Bug", "Developer", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <hr />
    @grid.GetHtml(
    columns:
    grid.Columns(
                grid.Column("BugNumber", "Bug Number"),
                grid.Column("Name", "Name"),
                grid.Column("Status", "Status"),
                grid.Column("Severity", "Severity"),
                grid.Column("Priority", "Priority"),
                grid.Column("DueDate", "Due Date"),
                grid.Column(format: @<text> @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) </text>),
                grid.Column(format: @<text> @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) </text>)
                                                                                                                                                    )
                                                                                                                                                    )
}
```

Thankx